# Interaction of Warmage Edge class ability and damage multipliers

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Is the extra damage from the Warmage Edge class ability multiplied in case of critical damage or empowered spell ?

"[...] **Whenever a warmage casts a spell that deals hit point damage, he adds his Intelligence bonus (if any) to the amount of damage dealt.** [...]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Empowered Spell, No. Critical Hit, Yes.**

Warmage Edge is not a variable effect. [Empower Spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#empowerSpell) states: "All variable, numeric effects of an empowered spell are increased by one-half." The same would be true with [Maximize Spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#maximizeSpell) - there is nothing to maximize; the damage is constant no matter what spell or how many dice you roll per spell.

Warmage Edge is not precision damage, nor is it energy damage. Upon confirmation of a critical hit, you would double your damage dice, and also double your Warmage Edge.

---

**Example**

You hit an opponent with an [Acid Splash](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/acidSplash.htm). You rolled a natural 20. Your DM asks you to confirm if it is a critical hit. You rolled another natural 20. Since the default critical damage multiplier is x2, and you have an 18 intelligence, your critical hit damage rolls would be 1d3+4 and 1d3+4, or a total of 2d3+8.

---

**What exactly does a critical hit mean?**

> A critical hit means that you roll your damage more than once, **with all your usual bonuses**, and add the rolls together.

---

**What if there is no attack roll?**

> A spell that requires an attack roll can score a critical hit. A spell attack that requires no attack roll cannot score a critical hit.

Comment: So an empowered (and *not* cast by a warmage) [*magic missile*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicMissile.htm) deals ((1d4)×1½)+1 points of damage *not* (1d4+1)×1½ points of damage?

Comment: "For example, an
empowered magic missile deals 1½ times its normal damage (roll
1d4+1 and multiply the result by 1½ for each missile)." (PHB1 p.93) Seems clear to me that the +1 *is* part of the "roll" and *is* multiplied.

Comment: @topquark Correct. Related to my answer, Warmage Edge is not a part of a roll. A direct comparison would be not multiplying a Sneak Attack on a critical hit.

Comment: @Ruut - That's not a direct comparison.  Critical hits have specific exception language for 'extra bonus dice'.  Whether or not a warmage's magic missile includes the warmage edge as 'normal damage' is largely up to individual GMs.  You're implying rules text exists that does not actually exist.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes.

From the SRD on critical hits -

> Exception: Extra damage dice over and above a weapon’s normal damage is not multiplied when you score a critical hit.

From the Combat section of the 3.5e PHB -

> **Spells and Critical Hits:**
>
> A spell that requires an attack roll can score a critical hit. A spell attack that requires no attack roll cannot score a critical hit

From pg72 of Complete Arcane

> **Feats and Weaponlike Spells**
>
> Any spell that requires an attack roll and deals damage functions as a weapon in certain respects.  As such, several feats that improve weapon performance can be used to enhance weaponlike spells.

The only thing critical hits do not multiply is bonus dice above and beyond the weapon's normal damage.  The spell's base damage is the 'weapon' in this circumstance.  Ergo, you would double the damage added from int, from Fiery Spell, from Weapon Specialization (Ranged Spells), etc, you're fine.

In Pathfinder, when you Empower a spell, you roll an additional half-sized die (like a d3, or a d2) for each empowered die.  Those would probably be 'bonus dice', and therefore not be multiplied by a critical hit.

However, in 3.5, you just multiply the result of the spell's rolls by 1.5x, so it would stack with a critical hit.

Keep in mind how 3.5 handles multiplication, though - 1.5x + 2x = 2.5x, not 3.5x or the result of 1.5x + the result of 2x.

If you're using Sneak Attack to add +3d6 damage to a spell, that extra sneak attack damage would not be multiplied.  Similarly extra dice from *dragon fire inspiration* or any other ability that adds 'bonus dice'.